# How to detect chunk error (404) loaded on video element on Safari iOS when playing m3u8

Tags: ios, video-streaming, mobile-safari, http-live-streaming

Reproduce

1. Playing m3u8 playlist
2. After that, I stop streaming by cut the signal.
   => Player stop but don't fire error event.
   I can't catch that error to handle.

Many thanks for the comments, everyone!

Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>The video autoplay attribute</h1>
<video id="VIDEO" width="320" height="240" controls autoplay playsInline/>
<script>
    const linkPlay = "https://sgn-fpt-001-livecdn-vt.vieon.vn/7ed4de9c6e5740688d95878c8bd5a766/1654246367317/dvr_event/60b822a4-ef69-4886-b942-351ab352779a/playlist.m3u8"
    function init() {
        const video = document.getElementById("VIDEO")
        console.log(video)
        console.log(video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl'))
        video.src = linkPlay
        video.load()
        video.addEventListener('error', (e)=> {
            console.log('error', e)
        })
    }
    init();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

These are issue's image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

P/s: If you need to debug, you can pm me and I will play the playlist.
Regard

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).